# Ajuda com erro - comparações contra strings

Tags: javascript, string

Olá,
Boa noite!

Estou em uma plataforma de estudos no qual se executa exercícios e testes, o enunciado é:

Define a função hojeSeJoga, que receba por parâmetro uma string que informe o día da semana. Esta função deve retornar"Hoje é dia de futebol!!!" se parâmetro for "domingo", caso contrário deve retornar "Hoje não é dia de futebol :(".

**Fiz o seguinte código:**

```js
function hojeSeJoga(diaDaSemana) {
    if (diaDaSemana == "domingo") {
        return 'Hoje é dia de futebol!!!';
    } else {
        return 'Hoje não é dia de futebol :('
    }
}
```

> E a plataforma informa que:

Sua solução funcionou, mas há coisas para melhorar

Objetivos que não foram atendidos:

hojeSeJoga faz comparações contra strings

Resultados do teste:
hojeSeJoga("domingo") deveria dizer se joga

hojeSeJoga("terça") devería dizer que não joga

**O que está faltando?**

Obrigada!

Comment: Posso perguntar que plataforma é essa? Estão chovendo perguntas parecidas aqui, essa mesmo já foi perguntada de outras maneiras umas 4 vezes.

Comment: Nossa, a minha é Digital House.

Comment: Obrigado. São muitas perguntas parecidas. Talvez essa escola esteja indicando o site para os alunos tirarem dúvidas. Pelo que eu vi das perguntas iguais à sua, não dá pra saber se esses requisitos (como evitar comparar com string) estão explícitos desde o começo. Porque se não estiverem eu consideraria o exercício ruim. Além disso, se é pra evitar comparar com string, seria bom te explicarem o motivo, em vez de tentarem enfiar um mito na sua cabeça. Enfim, boa sorte nos estudos.

Comment: Não estão claros, o enunciado do exercício é desta forma. Por isso ficam várias dúvidas e erros na hora do teste. Obrigada!

Comment: @bfavaretto os exercícios são todo péssimos e a impressão que dá é que estão iludindo as pessoas que estão fazendo.

Comment: Realmente é o caso de ficarmos atentos, vem muito teste porcaria da tal plataforma, e tenho visto muitos testes ruins ultimamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var domingo = "domingo";
var segunda = "segunda";
var terca = "terca";
var quarta = "quarta";
var quinta = "quinta";
var sexta = "sexta";
var sabado = "sabado";
function hojeSeJoga (diaDaSemana) {
  if (diaDaSemana === domingo) {
    return "Hoje é dia de futebol!!!";
  } else {
    return "Hoje não é dia de futebol :(";
  }
}
```

Usa esta que vai resolver...

Comment: Deu certo! Obrigada!

Comment: Maravilha... tbm estou fazendo estes exercícios, mas estou parado um pouco mais a frente... rs...

Comment: Pra que definir esse monte de variável que não é usada? Se a plataforma implica com a comparação de strings, bastaria uma variável para "domingo", não? Tipo `var diaDeFutebol = 'domingo'; if (diaDaSemana === diaDeFutebol) {...`

Comment: Acredito que vc tenha razão, mas tbm sou noob em JS e esta foi a única solução que o site do curso aceitou...

Comment: A plataforma implica com qualquer coisa  bfavaretto♦, mas esta forma também aceitou. Obrigada!

Comment: @bfavaretto ja notamos isso em outras questões, tem uns casos que a plataforma reclama de comparação com literal, como se isso por si só fosse um problema. Deve ser mais uma daquelas de "boas práticas", que obriga o usuário a inventar moda só pq quem fez a plataforma gosta assim.